# pandas bar plot not taking list of colours

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, bar-chart

I'm trying to colour a bar chart with different colours, but when I pass a list of colours to the `color` argument, it still colors all bars the same.

```
combi_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Labels', 'Number'])

label_list = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight']
              

 
int_list = [302,11,73,10,68,36,42,30]
combi_df['Labels'] = label_list
combi_df['Number'] = int_list



fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)


box = ax.get_position()
ax.set_position([box.x0, box.y0, box.width * 0.8, box.height])

c = ['#1b9e77', '#a9f971', '#fdaa48','#6890F0','#A890F0','#fdaa48','#6890F0','#A890F0']


combi_df[['Number']].plot(kind='bar',color=c ,legend=True, fontsize=10,ax=ax)
ax.legend(ax.patches, combi_df['Labels'], loc='upper center',bbox_to_anchor=(0.75, 1))
ax.set_xlabel("Labels", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Number of occurences", fontsize=12)

plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

I have tried a number of things to make it work, including [How to put colors in a matplotlib bar chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973404/setting-different-bar-color-in-matplotlib-python%5D), [Setting Different Bar color in matplotlib Python [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58121759/how-to-put-colors-in-a-matplotlib-bar-chart) and [How to set Different Color(s) for Bars of Bar Plot in Matplotlib?](https://www.tutorialkart.com/matplotlib-tutorial/matplotlib-pyplot-bar-plot-different-colors-for-bars/)

Comment: `color` is the color for *each column*. You are only plotting one column of data.  What if you just use matplotlib directly, not pandas? `ax.bar(combi_df.index, combi_df['Number'], color=c)`?

Comment: @BigBen this one works, but it does not mirror the changes in the legend? would i have to add another argument for this?

Comment: Perhaps you want `ax.bar(combi_df['Labels'], combi_df['Number'], color=c)`.

Comment: If the labels aren't too long, it would be much better to add them as x tick labels.

Comment: @JohanC unfortunately (for me), the labels are longer and I would like to add them as a legend, because shrinking size/ rotating them does not look good.

Comment: You can also add newlines in the strings to plot them over multiple lines. To have them in the legend, you could call `ax.bar(...)` in a loop, for each individual bar.

Comment: To have more space for the tick labels, horizontal bars might be considered. `ax.barh(labels, values)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commented, [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) sets colors by column and you only have one column, so one possibility is to switch back to the vanilla [`pyplot.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html).

If you still want to use a pandas plot, pivot your `Labels` into columns:

```
combi_df.pivot(columns='Labels', values='Number').plot.bar(color=c, stacked=True, ax=ax)
```

[image]

Or make it horizontal and replace the legend with `yticklabels`:

```
combi_df.pivot(columns='Labels', values='Number').plot.barh(color=c, stacked=True, legend=False, ax=ax)
ax.set_yticklabels(combi_df['Labels'])
```

[image]